Regex replacement problems
I am trying to write a regex replacment that will do the following but have tried for several hours to no avail.
I have the following regex: (?:\> \[!anki\]-) ([^\n]+)\n(.+(?:\n(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*))*)
with the following replacement: (?:\> \[!anki\]-) ([^\n]+)\n(.+(?:\n(?:^.{1,3}$|^.{4}(?<!<!--).*))*)(\n<!-- end of flashcard -->|\n)
Because I want to achieve the following:
> [!anki]- Title
> Answer

> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
<!-- end of flashcard -->

> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
> Another line
> Another line

> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
^7a6a36

To become this:
> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
<!-- end of flashcard -->


> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
<!-- end of flashcard -->


> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
> Another line
> Another line
<!-- end of flashcard -->


> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
^7a6a36
<!-- end of flashcard -->


i.e. if "<!-- end of flashcard --> is not present then add it and if some line of text after the flashcard begins with "^" and then some text then it should be placed underneath the <!-- end of flashcard --> (the ^7a6a36).
If this is better done with multiple regex replacements instead of one then thats fine.

Note im using javascript regex with multiline mode on

Thank you

You could capture what is before <!-- end of flashcard --> and then optionally match it at the end so that it is not present after the replacement to prevent duplicate lines.
(> \[!anki]- .+(?:\n(?!<!--).+)*)(?:\n<!-- end of flashcard -->)?

The pattern matches:

( Capture group 1

> \[!anki]- .+ Match > [!anki]-  and 1+ times any character without a newline
(?:\n(?!<!--).+)* Optionally repeat matching a newline, then assert not <!-- directly to the right and match 1+ times any character


) Close group 1
(?:\n<!-- end of flashcard -->)? Optionally match a newline and <!-- end of flashcard -->

Replace using capture group 1 denoted by $1:
$1\n<!-- end of flashcard -->

Regex demo
Using JavaScript:


const regex = /(> \[!anki]- .+(?:\n(?!<!--).+)*)(?:\n<!-- end of flashcard -->)?/g;
const str = `> [!anki]- Title
> Answer

> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
<!-- end of flashcard -->

> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
> Another line
> Another line

> [!anki]- Title
> Answer
^7a6a36`;

const result = str.replace(regex, `$1\n<!-- end of flashcard -->`);
console.log(result);




Or an alternative matching lines that start with > or ^
(> \[!anki]- .+(?:\n[>^].*)*)(?:\n<!-- end of flashcard -->)?

Regex demo

Alternate approach seems more efficient

If the sample input is fully accurate to your data, this is a quick and dirty way to get it done since all you care about is the space between the flashcards:
(\w)[\s>]+(\[!anki\])

replaced with
$1\n<!-- end of flashcard -->\n\n\n$2

The matching regex identifies a single word character followed by only whitespace or the > character that shows up at the beginning of lines until it hits an [!anki], in which case you can add some line breaks and an <!-- end of flashcard --> into that space
